# Why does Firefox remove non-breaking spaces in input fields?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, typography

I have a [bépo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%89PO) keyboard and often use [non-breaking spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space), which I can insert with Shift + Space.

Now here's the thing that baffles me: in all input fields, textareas, etc., Firefox seems to *replace non-breaking spaces with normal spaces*. Google Chrome and Chromium don't.

Here's the reproducible test I'm doing:

- I enter `free donut` into a Duckduckgo search bar / StackExchange textarea / whatever, with a non-breaking space between `free` and `donut`.
- I copy-paste the two words inside Emacs, which by default displays non-breaking spaces with an horizontal bar.
  With Chrome, the non-breaking space appears. With Firefox, it doesn't.

(I think the different results eliminate the possibility that it'd come from the copy-paste manipulation)

Related question: [How does copying and pasting non-breaking spaces compare in different systems/browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178602/how-does-copying-and-pasting-non-breaking-spaces-compare-in-different-systems-br)

Comment: I have the same question. This has been a known issue for the last 15 years and is still being discussed: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=359303